# Add class to any element in TinyMCE visual mode

Tags: tinymce

I'm looking to add some scripting to my TinyMCE editor that allows me to right click on any element and apply a class to it. For example, if I right click inside a bullet list, a context menu pops up where I can choose from a list of bullet examples. Clicking one of them will automatically add the class for that bullet's look and feel to the parent UL element of my bullet list.

I'd also like to be able to click outside an element in order to insert whole elements.

I'd be surprised if something like this does not already exist and I'm looking for examples.

I'm using WordPress and I'll be adding this capability to my theme.